# Vlookup checking for multiple values and adding them together

Tags: excel

I have a table called "data" that has a bunch of data with dates and IDs along with 2 return values(we can call `A` and `B`) and a value for the number of hits(`C`)

I wrote this script:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(F$1&$A4&"1"&"0",data!$A:$F,6,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(F$1&$A4&"0"&"0",data!$A:$F,6,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(F$1&$A4&"1"&"0",data!$A:$F,6,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(F$1&$A4&"0"&"0",data!$A:$F,6,FALSE),0)
```

My current formula adds and returns the approiate value only if both `A=1 and B=0` and `A=0 and B=0` values are found. If only `A=1 and B=0` is found or only `A=0 and B=0`is found then it will just return 0.

I want to check the data table and return all values(`C`) that have either `A=1 and B=0` or `A=0 and B=0` for that specific date and ID number. I also want to add the values together. How can I edit my formula to do this?

Comment: You could add a couple helper columns with the conditions.  It will make your life much easier when building the lookup.  Other than that, it's just a combination of `AND(,)` and `OR(,)`.

Comment: Anyway you guys can show me an example? I'm pretty new with Excel formulas